# Modificar el archivo string.xml desde codigo java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Estoy internacionalizando una aplicación y hay parte de la información que viene desde una Base de datos, por lo que me gustaría meter esa información en un string vacío cuando llegue al teléfono y desde código java traducir y posteriormente cambiar el contenido de los string.xml español e ingles.

```
<string name="animal">conejo</string> //Carpeta string.xml (es)

<string name="animal">rabbit</string> //Carpeta string.xml (en)
```

Si existe una forma de extraer la información tendrá que haber otra para modificarla parecida a:

```
String text = getString(R.string.animal);
```

Cual seria el equivalente pero para modificar string.xml para cada idioma?

muchas gracias de antemano y saludo.

Comment: de una base de datos externa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Si defines en tu proyecto varios archivos `strings.xml` para diferentes lenguajes, estos recursos son de solo lectura y no pueden modificarse**:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
       values-ro/
           strings.xml
```

al llamar un string contenido en el archivo,

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.animal);
```

obtendrías su respectivo texto de acuerdo a la configuración de tu dispositivo:

```
values/ -> rabbit
values-es/ -> conejo
values-fr/ -> lapine
values-ro/ -> iepure
```

por lo tanto si deseas editar los textos definidos se perdería el objetivo de esta característica.

[Configuración de diferentes idiomas](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages?hl=es-419)

tendrías que buscar otra opción como crear un archivo o una base de datos donde tuvieras precargados todos los textos y su respectiva traducción, incluso podrías consultar esta información a través de un Web Service el cual permitiera también editar la información.

Comment: ok muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Creo tener ya una solución.